# How do I disable The Just in Time Debugger?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010, iis

Just provisioned a new server running IIS and Server 2012 and SQL Server 2012.  I also installed SQL Server Management Studio tool so I can quickly inspect databases without the need to open a remote connection.

When I browse an ASP.NET sites remotely, I get a Just-in-time debgugger exception dialog when an error is encountered in addition to the yellow screen. The dialog stays up on the server and piles up unless I RDP and manually close all the dialog boxes.

The only way to disable this is by removing Visual Studio Shell 2010 (integrated) using the control panel. The side effect is that I can no longer use SSMS.

Most of the available solutions are outdated or don't work.  The registry settings are no longer applicable and most articles concerning this issue are old. Microsoft's official documentation is a rat's nest of broken links.  Moreover, many users are confusing IE's script debugging dialog with this issue. Although they are related and similar, this specific issue is tied to Visual Studio's runtime environment.

Any ideas?

ASIDE: I can't believe Microsoft has this "feature" on a product that is installed on a production server.  I am just floored by the incompetence of a multi-billion dollar corporation.  I've seen my question asked since at least since 2005 with no official solution that works. I just have to ask one last time for sanity checking. I want to make sure I'm not the one who is "thick" in the head here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to disable Jist-In-Time debugging using the Debug options dialog inside Visual Studio. The registry keys are also well documented here.

See:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5hs4b7a6.aspx

Aside: I think it's not a wise thing to install a management studio on a production server. This is what management workstations are for. Remote connections from a management station can be pre-configured and stored so that it doesn't take much effort. That way you can keep your production environment clean.

Comment: Thanks for the tip!  I've always feel like I should turn off all inbound ports unless absolutely needed, hence the need to have SMSS installed on the server.

I've seen the document you're talking about and have tried all the settings in Visual Studio.  I've also tried but couldn't find the registry settings mentioned in the document.

Comment: If you restrict the inbound port to only accept incomign traffic fromt he management workstation you're probably more secure than when you install debuggers and development tools to the server.

Comment: Thanks. Do you think the answer to this question is: "Don't install SQL Management Studio?"

Comment: It should not be, the registry settings should do their work. But it's a recommendation nonetheless.

Comment: I have yet to see the alert.  I removed both VS shells using the control panel and discovered SSMS no longer worked. I did a repair installation and SSMS started working again, but this time I am no longer getting the popup.  Can't figure out why this is happening.  Looks like the settings were somehow cached.

Answer (score 7):

To disable Just-In-Time debugging by editing the registry

In the Start menu, click Run.
In the Run dialog box, type regedit, then click OK.
In the Registry Editor window, locate and delete the follow registry keys:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AeDebug\Debugger
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\DbgManagedDebugger
```

If your computer is running a 64-bit operating system, delete the following registry keys also:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\WindowsNT\CurrentVersion\AeDebug\Debugger
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\.NETFramework\DbgManagedDebugger
```

Take care not to accidentally delete or change any other registry keys.

Instead of deleting it, you can also just (temporarily) rename the `AeDebug` key for the bitness of your choice to something else, e.g. `AeDebug-disable!`

Comment: The description is originated in [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5hs4b7a6.aspx).

Comment: I've done this some months ago. Today, I took a look just to discover that the registry keys are present again! Maybe every update of SQL Server Management Studio (or similar Visual Studio based tools) re-installs these keys again?!?

Comment: This worked for me on Windows Server 2012 R2, ASP.NET 4.8. Hopefully OP can accept this as the answer.

Answer (score 3):

For `server 2012`, `IIS`, and `SSMS 2014` we tried all three registry three deletions and those did not work.

What did work was old school renaming the JIT Debug executable.

Renamed these files.

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32\vsjitdebugger.exe  
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\vsjitdebugger.exe
```

Renamed this folder

```
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\VS7Debug
```

Answer (score 2):

As a follow-up to [nfox's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24409301/107625), I've created a registry file that you can simple use instead of searching manually through regedit.exe.

**1.) Copy this script to your clipboard:**

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AeDebug]
"Debugger"=-

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework]
"DbgManagedDebugger"=-

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AeDebug]
"Debugger"=-

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\.NETFramework]
"DbgManagedDebugger"=-
```

**2.) Save it to a file with the .reg extension:**

E.g. to a file named

```
C:\Users\<user name>\Desktop\DisableJit.reg
```

**3.) Double click the file**

After confirming the appearing message box, the keys are getting deleted.

**5.) Alternatively: Download file**

If this is too much effort, you can download the registry file from here:

- [disable-the-just-in-time-debugger-windows-64-bit.reg](https://www.dropbox.com/s/19r5fd2gjq54qt0/disable-the-just-in-time-debugger-windows-64-bit.reg?dl=0)
- [disable-the-just-in-time-debugger-windows-64-bit.zip](https://www.dropbox.com/s/61kiq127pe012gr/disable-the-just-in-time-debugger-windows-64-bit.zip?dl=0) (As a ZIP)

Download and then double-click it.

---

This tip was simply taken from the MSDN article "[Just-In-Time Debugging in Visual Studio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5hs4b7a6.aspx)".

The syntax on how to delete registry keys via a .reg file was taken from the MSDN KB article "[How to add, modify, or delete registry subkeys and values by using a .reg file](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/310516)".